# How to limit request rates in .map loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-product-api

I'm requesting amazon product advertising api with code like this:

```
products = asins.map do |asin|
  item = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, response_group: :Large)

  json = {asin: item.get_element('Item').get('ASIN'),
          manufacturer: item.get_element('ItemAttributes').get('Manufacturer'),
          model: item.get_element('ItemAttributes').get('Model')}
end
```

And get 503 error: `You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.`

I found out that they want 1 request per second.
What's the best way of doing it in my case?

Comment: Do they not have an api for looking up multiple items at once?

Comment: I think they allow max 10 ItemIds per ItemLookup request. But I believe amazon-ecs gem I use does not support it. Even if they allow 10 items, question is still valid as I have hundreds of items to lookup.

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa could you not just add a `sleep 1` into the map loop?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just decelerate by waiting a second between to iterations:

```
products = asins.map do |asin|
  sleep 1 # wait one second before doing the next API call
  item = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, response_group: :Large)

  {
    asin:         item.get_element('Item').get('ASIN'),
    manufacturer: item.get_element('ItemAttributes').get('Manufacturer'),
    model:        item.get_element('ItemAttributes').get('Model')
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sleep` is for sure the first solution that comes to mind. In my opinion, it's not an elegant one, becacause it's totally not managable. I would think of some queueing system to do the work - maybe sidekiq using a self triggering worker?

Some simplified code:

```
# some kind of queueing logic, to fetch asins
asin = AsinQueue.fetch

# trigger first worker
LookupWorker.perform_async(asin)

# and the worker itself:
class LookupWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(asin)
    item = Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup(asin, response_group: :Large)
    # all the domain logic 

    # queue next lookup
    next_asin = AsinQueue.fetch
    LookupWorker.perform_in(1.second, next_asin)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemLookup supports batch requests. You can lookup up to 10 items at once.